# Grep with complex regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, grep

How to grep for a complex regex in bash?

I'm trying to grep a file `backend.conf` for:

```
cat backend.conf | grep "server (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

But I am not seeing any matches, even though the contents of `backend.conf` has:

```
server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
```

Which should be matching.

Comment: `grep -E "server (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" backend.conf`

Comment: Still no match. Hummmm.

Comment: It works for me with your given sample data

Comment: @anubhava And for me, too. The OP didn't post his OS, though, so maybe he's on something with a very old or very weird grep that doesn't support extended regular expressions.

Comment: `egrep (GNU grep) 2.16` this is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Your problem is the non-capturing groups. See the PCRE section of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35444071/1301972) below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use Extended Regular Expressions with Grep

Standard grep uses a regular expression engine that doesn't understand ranges, and that requires special characters to be escaped. Extended regular expressions will handle these atoms and operators properly, so use `egrep`, `grep -E`, or `pcregrep` depending on what's available on your particular system.

```
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' |
    egrep 'server (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
```

### Use the PCRE Library

Note that GNU grep (at least through v2.20) doesn't support some of the atoms you are using. In particular, non-capturing groups with `?:` are not supported without the Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) library, which  many Linux distributions do not compile into GNU grep by default.

To see if you have PCRE support, try `ldd $(which grep) | fgrep -i pcre` to see if the PCRE library is linked in. If it is, you may just need to add the `-P` or `--perl-regexp` flags to enable it for your expressions.

If you do *not* have PCRE compiled in, then either capture the group:

```
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' |
    egrep 'server ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
```

or install and use `pcregrep` instead:

```
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' |     
    pcregrep 'server (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
```

which certainly *does* support non-capturing groups.

Comment: I'm not getting a match `echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | egrep "server (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"`

Comment: @Justin Are you getting an error? What OS are you on? Are you using a non-standard character set? What does `grep --version` tell you?

Comment: `egrep (GNU grep) 2.16` this is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Remove the `?:` part and it will work. Also if you are interested about the IPs, you may try: `echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -Po "(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}"`. (In case -P and -o are valid options for that grep version).

Answer (score 0):

By default grep uses the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax, that gives:

```
grep 'server \([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}'
```

If you want something lighter you can use the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax:

```
grep -E 'server ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Note that none of these syntaxes doesn't know what is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

For me works:

```
echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -E "server ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

(Note the simpe `(` instead of the `(?:` in the other answers and your question.)

Answer (score 0):

I can work. I checked with grep (GNU grep) 2.20

```
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -E "server ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]"
```

(command is same as other answers)

Note:
You might easily confirm your regular expression if you use -o option of `grep`. `grep -o PATTERN` output only string which matches PATTERN

Example:

```
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -o -E "server [0-9]{1,3}"
server 172
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -o -E "server ([0-9]{1,3})"
server 172
$ echo 'server 172.31.21.45 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;' | grep -o -E "server (?:[0-9]{1,3})"
$
```